# Invoking Kernel from MATLAB Low Performance

Tags: matlab, cuda, gpu

I have invoked a CUDA kernel from my MATLAB implementation; however my CPU results are faster than my GPU implementation. I know larger matrices gain better performance, but when I also try for large sizes, I get low GPU performance.

The results are:
CPU: 0.000006
GPU: 0.00134
My kernel and MATLAB code is below:

Thanks in Advance!

```
matrix.cu

__global__ void matrix_mult2(double *A, double *B, double * C) {
   int x =  threadIdx.x;

C[x] = A[x] * B[x];


}



main.m
kernel = parallel.gpu.CUDAKernel( 'matrix_mult2.ptx', ...
                              'matrix_mult2.cu' );


kernel.ThreadBlockSize = [25,1,1];
kernel.GridSize = [1,1];


A = parallel.gpu.GPUArray.rand(5,5,'double');
B = parallel.gpu.GPUArray.rand(5,5,'double');
C = parallel.gpu.GPUArray.zeros(5,5);

C = feval(kernel,A,B,C);
```

Comment: What sizes are the results for?

Comment: I was trying to determine if for relatively small matrices do I receive a low performance and I was also trying to determine the best config for cuda threads since that may also effect performance.

Comment: Thank you for your reply!

I also tried for large matrices 621 x 1176, and the GPU (0.00834) performance is still slower than the CPU (0.001513)
Where,
 kernel.ThreadBlockSize = [1024,1,1];
kernel.GridSize = [713,1];

tic
C = feval(kernel,A,B,C);
wait(gpuDevice(1));
C=gather(C)
time = toc

My CPU version:
is A=rand(621,1176);
B=rand(621,1176);
C=rand(621,1176);

tic
C=A.*B
toc

Thanks in Advanced

Comment: Two things: When running a benchmark performing the calculation only once is usually not the most accurate. Next to this, yoy did not exactly specify your question. Are you interested in why this happens, what would be the fastest or on how to improve gpu speed?

Answer (score 1):

You need to give the GPU some real work to do. In your current example, the only time-consuming operations are copying the data to the GPU and back. As the CPU doesn't have to perform these steps, it has an obvious advantage here. Try e.g. a real matrix multiplication of large matrices (not an element wise multiplication).

In slightly more formal terms, your kernel is PCIe bandwidth bound. To amortize the time spent copying *N* elements forth and back, you need to do some operations that are a lot more expensive than the data copying. Elementwise multiplication is cheap and scales linearly with *N*. Multiplication of *N×N*-matrices scales with *N*<sup>3</sup> while the data transfer only scales with *N*<sup>2</sup>, so for large enough matrices matrix multiplication on the GPU will be faster than on the CPU.